# Error en python django Could not parse the remainder: '['fields']['Nombre']' from 'record['fields']['Nombre']'

Tags: python, html, django, api, airtable

I am new to Python and Django what I am trying to do is to connect to airtable through API, and I want to display that data in a table in html but at the time of displaying it I have that error, I already made the connection correctly to airtable.

I tried to connect to another database, I checked the html tags and the names of the variables but I didn't find anything concrete.

Error during template rendering.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for record in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ record['fields']['Nombre'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ record['fields']['Apellido'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ record['fields']['Email'] }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<td>{{ record['fields']['Nombre'] }}</td>`, try this -

```
        <td>{{ record.fields.Nombre }}</td>
```